# Check for version number during `cofigure`

Tags: configure, autoconf

I have an old `cofigure.in` file which checks for that the version of `zsh` is new enough:

```
if test ! -z "$PATH_OF_ZSH"; then
   echo "Checking zsh's version number:"
   if zsh --version 2>&1 | grep 'zsh 4\.'; then
      echo "OK"
   else
      NEED_NEW_ZSH="y"
   fi
fi

if test x"$NEED_NEW_ZSH" = x"y"; then
    echo "Error: old zsh program found. You need a new version of zsh, please..."
fi
```

The problem with this solution is the unsupport of `zsh` version 5.0.7. and others.

I have tried with

```
if test ! -z "$PATH_OF_ZSH"; then
   echo "Checking zsh's version number:"
   if zsh --version 2>&1 | grep 'zsh [4-9][0-9]*\.'; then
      echo "OK"
   else
      NEED_NEW_ZSH="y"
   fi
fi

if test x"$NEED_NEW_ZSH" = x"y"; then
    echo "Error: old zsh program found. You need a new version of zsh, please..."
fi
```

But I still have error:

> solid@pralor:~/CMWP> autoconf
>
> solid@pralor:~/CMWP> ./configure
>
> [...]
>
> Checking zsh's version number:
>
> Error: old zsh program found. You need a new version of zsh, please

**UPDATE**

The `configure` script has changed uncorrectly to:

```
if zsh --version 2>&1 | grep 'zsh 4-90-9*\.'; then
```

instead of the expected

```
if zsh --version 2>&1 | grep 'zsh [4-9][0-9]*\.'; then
```

New question: how to change correctly `configure.in` to reach the expected change?

Comment: What does `zsh --version | grep -o 'zsh [4-9][0-9]*\.'; echo $?` output? Maybe the confiugre result is cached? Have you verified that your change is also in the `configure` script and not just in `configure.in`?

Comment: `zsh --version | grep -o 'zsh [4-9][0-9]*\.'; echo $` results: `zsh 5.
$`

Comment: But the `configure` script has changed incorrectly :/ please see UPDATE!